# Is there any method to get youtube video link that are currently playing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, youtube, youtube-api

I want to make one android app that will run in background. When someone open youtube app and start to play any video That video link will automatically copied and one popup will visible to user to download that video. Assume User will give all the permission that app needs.
I tried to google it but didn't find anything. So is any brilliant mind is here?

So basically My App needs "youtube video link" when user play any video in youtube.

Comment: You can only download the video inside the Youtube app (legally).
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7381437?hl=en#zippy=

Comment: Hi Rizul, I want videolink of youtube that the user is playing . My plan is to do many stuff with that link.

Comment: I don't know if they are similar things for android but on a computer I would use `youtube-dl` or `yt-dlp`.

Comment: You can use a [Media-Player](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to check if a video is being played or not.